# How to create link in email body that doesn't redirect just send request?

Tags: javascript, html, email

Is it possible to create a link in email that user can click to indicate their response without having to open a new window/tab.

Like how google calendar does it, that asks in email if you are going to event, yes|no|maybe and you dont leave email .

Comment: It's highly unlikely. The Google Calendar button is only available due to the tight integration between GMail and Calendar. Were you to open that invitation email in another client (Outlook, Thunderbird, etc) you would not have those buttons.

Comment: The JavaScript may not work in an email.

Comment: i looked in email header there links like this: `reply:
Accept - https:www....
Decline - https://www....
Maybe - https://www.....` then same links are repeated in a tags so they dont open new window but just send request

Comment: is that standard